# Deleting elements from an array in PHP having more than 1 value in common

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array $element like this below with a list of words followed by a number

```
car 1
house 1
boat 1
book 3
question 2
about 2
draft 2
bounce 7
tag 5
dog 5
```

How can I remove from this array all the words having more than one number in common ?
I need this as result

```
book 3
bounce 7
```

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself so far to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes I did, I posted here because I cannot find a way to do this in a good way, I didn't post here because I am searching someone to do the work for me , if you are thinking this .

Comment: Just posting what you have tried can be a good starting point.  It may be easy to fix or help others understand where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your array is :

```
 $myArray = [

'car' => 1,
'house' => 1,
'boat' =>1,
'book' => 3,
'question' => 2,
'about' => 2,
'draft' => 2,
'bounce' => 7,
'tag' => 5,
'dog' => 5

];
```

You can remove duplicate values in this way :

Loop through the array, and store the value in a variable. I am storing it in a $lastValue variable.

in the loop check if the new value is equal to the last one, if true then start the loop again and find all the values of array equal to the last value and remove them using unset().

```
$lastValue = '';

//key is cat, house, boat ...
//value is key value 1,1,1,3...

foreach($myArray as $key => $value){

    if($value == $lastValue){

        foreach($myArray as $key2 => $value2){

            if($value2 == $lastValue){

                unset($myArray[$key2]);
            }
        }
    }


    $lastValue = $value;
    
    
}

print_r($myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the array and store the values in an associative array using the number as the key and whatever you want as a final result as the value.
While looping you might encounter keys that already exist. In this case you need to track the key to prevent it from being added again in another array and remove the value from the associative array.

In the end, only those elements that do not have duplicate keys, will be in the associative array.

Can look like this:

```
<?php
$values = [
    ['car', 1],
    ['house', 1],
    ['boat', 1],
    ['book', 3],
    ['question', 2],
    ['about', 2],
    ['draft', 2],
    ['bounce', 7],
    ['tag', 5],
    ['dog', 5],
];
$result = [];
$duplicateIndex = [];

foreach($values as $value) {
    if(in_array($value[1], $duplicateIndex)) {
        continue;
    }
    if(isset($result[$value[1]])) {
        $duplicateIndex[] = $value[1];
        unset($result[$value[1]]);
    } else {
        $result[$value[1]] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump(array_values($result));
```

There are several other options as well. One would be to loop twice. Count how often a key occurs in the first run and add those with one occurrence to a result array in the second loop.